# Whether to migrate database or logins first?

Tags: sql-server, migration

In a SQL server 2012 to SQL server 2019 migration, is it recommended to migrate the databases first or the logins first?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't really matter as long as you accomplish both correctly. If you're going to use a backup of your `master` database to restore to the new server, as the way to transfer Logins, then I'd probably recommend restoring that database first anyway, just to ensure if any subsequent changes to `master` occur in your new server, they aren't lost.

Also, after you've migrated everything over, you should verify you have no [orphaned users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/troubleshoot-orphaned-users-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) otherwise you can resolve them per the linked Microsoft docs.

Comment: Updated the question contents to specify it is a 2012 to 2019 migration so can't move the master system db as that isn't supported

Comment: @variable Gotcha, then even more so, as my answer mentions, it shouldn't matter. Just make sure to double check for orphaned users after you're done migrating, per the Microsoft docs I provided.

Comment: One advantage of doing the database first, is that the login might have that database as the default database. Trying the login first would fail if the specified default database doesn't exist.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi Interesting, but wouldn't (in most cases) then the Login fail if it didn't exist yet as well, despite the database and it's Users being there?

Comment: Yes, it would fail. My suggestion is that you restore the database, and directly after that you create he logins (having the same SID). If you do reverse order, then creation of login will fail of that database is the default.